# Problem with System.assertequals in test class code

Tags: trigger, unit-test

I have below trigger code :

```
trigger updateopportunities on Account(after update) 
{
    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Account ac : Trigger.new)
    {
        if(ac.Status__c=='Cancelled')
            accountIds.add(ac.id);
    }
    List<Opportunity> oppsToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();
    for(Opportunity opp : [select id, StageName from Opportunity where AccountId in: accountIds])
    {
         opp.StageName='Closed - Cancelled';
         oppsToUpdate.add(opp);
    }
    update oppsToUpdate;
}
```

And below is one of the Test Method for single record testing

```
@isTest
Public Class TestAccountOpportunity{
    public static testMethod void verify(){
        List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>{};
        Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
        insert a;
        Opportunity opp =new opportunity(Name='TestOpportunity',accountid=a.id,StageName='Prospecting',CloseDate=system.today(),Amount=1000);
        insert Opp; 
        a.status__c = 'Cancelled';    
        update a;
        system.assertequals(opp.stageName,'Closed - Cancelled');
    }
}
```

The expected output as per trigger should be the stage value of Opportunity is 'Closed - Cancelled' . But System.assertequals still shows it as 'Prospecting' only. Any idea on whats going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reselect the Opportunity before you can do an assert. Otherwise it will still hold the old values.

```
a.Status__c = 'Cancelled';    
update a;
System.AssertEquals('Closed - Cancelled', [SELECT StageName FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :opp.Id].StageName);
```

Side note: please flip your asserts. The expected value comes first.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to requery your Opportunity after the update, the `opp` you have in memory is what you had set prior to the update.

So, you should do this prior to your assert:

```
opp = [Select StageName From Opportunity Where Id = :opp.Id];
```

Then do your assert which checking the `opp` after it was updated in the Database.

Answer (score 1):

In your test method the Opportunity record has the values you have set during creation. In order to retrieve the updated values (after the trigger execution) you need a SoQL query.

> update a;
>
> **opp = [SELECT id, stageName From Opportunity WHERE Id = :opp.Id];**
>
> system.assertequals(opp.stageName,'Closed - Cancelled');

Then the assertion should be ok